# How to save file to s3 after processing by ffmpeg using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, carrierwave

I am trying to convert the bit rate of the Mp3 file before uploading to S3, I can able to create version for the mp3 file but the version is not saving in s3 instead original file is uploading to s3.

```
  version :bitrate_96k do
    process :resample => "96"
  end

def resample(bitrate)
    tmp_path   = File.join( File.basename(current_path), "tmpfile" )
    File.rename current_path, tmp_path
    audio_details  = `ffmpeg -i '#{tmp_path}' 2>&1`.split(",").split("\n").flatten
    file_bitrate =  audio_details.grep(/bitrate/).grep(/bitrate/).join.split("bitrate: ").last.split("\s").first
    unless file_bitrate == bitrate
      `ffmpeg -i #{tmp_path.shellescape}  -acodec libmp3lame -y -ab 96k #{current_path.path}`
      File.unlink(current_path)
     FileUtils.mv(temp_path, current_path)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Stepping through `resample` in my head it looks like you're `File.unlink`ing the 96k output, not the input, and then you're copying the un-converted tmp_file back to current_path. Try changing:

```
  File.unlink(current_path)
  FileUtils.mv(tmp_path, current_path)
```

to

```
  File.unlink(tmp_path)
else
  FileUtils.mv(tmp_path, current_path)
```